# Is Difference Transformation required for LSTM?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, rnn

I am Working on univariate multiple-step **LSTM** sequence prediction. My LSTM model is failing to give a good prediction on My Data. From some online blogs, I saw that Difference Transform may reduce Data Complexity.
Difference Transformation is   Preferred on the **Arima** like-model. But I never saw such an operation
done on LSTM.

- what you people think, is differencing required for **LSTM**?

Comment: Before answering, can I ask you more details on your dataset? And how did you process your data before feeding them into the RNN?

Comment: My data has both increasing and decreasing trends .i feeded the data after normalization